# How is total debt calculated in yahoo website?

Tags: yahoo-finance

I'm looking into the balance sheet of MLI, https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/MLI/balance-sheet

In the most recent quarter report,

1. Current Debt is 556K
2. Long Term Debt is 1301K

The total debt should be 556K + 1301K = 1857K. However, the total debt in the statistics page is 35.56M: https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/MLI/key-statistics

How is that value added up?

**EDIT**

I looked into other sides,

1. https://companiesmarketcap.com/mueller-industries/total-debt/
2. https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/MLI/financials/annual/balance-sheet

All of them is 36M in total debt, which means Yahoo's data is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data aggregators like Yahoo often have bad data, especially for smaller companies where the data is not as heavily scrutinized.

I'm not able to reconcile the summary data on Yahoo with their actual [balance sheet](https://ir.muellerindustries.com/sec-filings/all-sec-filings/content/0000089439-23-000070/0000089439-23-000070.pdf):

[image: Balance Sheet]

Yahoo summary data is fine to use as an initial screen for analysis, but you should not assume that it is true if you are using it for actual investment decisions.  Always validate it against actual published financials.

Comment: You're right to compare with the original results. I looked into all of them and I figured out Yahoo is calculating the TTM value by summing up all interesting bearing debt from last 4 quarters.